# Adding widgets to toggle lines in all Bokeh subplots

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

So I'm trying to create a 6x6 grid of of plots where each plot has multiple lines.  I want to add Bokeh's `CheckboxGroup` widget to be able to toggle lines on and off for all of the plots.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to link the widget to **all** plots.  When I run this code the widget & all plots I am able to only toggle for the last plot.  Any suggestions?

```
# create a list of subplots to iterate over 
ps = [figure(background_fill_color='#DFDFE5', plot_width=200, 
                            plot_height=200) for i in range(36)] 

for i in range(len(ps)):
    # link the range of first plot with every other plot
    ps[i].x_range = ps[0].x_range
    ps[i].y_range = ps[0].y_range

    # axes labels
    ps[i].yaxis.axis_label = 'amplitude'
    ps[i].xaxis.axis_label = 'age'

    # plot data -- xaxis_arr & na are my data arrays
    a = ps[i].line(xaxis_arr, na[0][i][2], line_width=2, color='#1f77b4')
    b = ps[i].line(xaxis_arr, na[1][i][2], line_width=2, color='#ff7f0e')
    c = ps[i].line(xaxis_arr, na[2][i][2], line_width=2, color='#2ca02c')
    ps[i].title.text = i

    customJScode = """
        console.log(cb_obj.active);
        line0.visible = false;
        line1.visible = false;
        line2.visible = false;

        for (i in cb_obj.active) {
            //console.log(cb_obj.active[i]);
            if (cb_obj.active[i] == 0) {
                line0.visible = true;
            } else if (cb_obj.active[i] == 1) {
                line1.visible = true;
            } else if (cb_obj.active[i] == 2) {
                line2.visible = true;
            }
        }
    """

    callback = CustomJS(code=customJScode, args={} )
    checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=["toggleLine1", "toggleLine2", "toggleLine3"], 
                             active=[0,1,2], callback=callback)

    callback.args = dict(line0=a, line1=b, line2=c, checkbox=checkbox)

myplots = gridplot(ps, ncols=6)


layout = column(myplots, widgetbox(checkbox))
show(layout)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each step in your for loop, you are overwriting the callback attribute of your checkbox with a new code, and new arguments, that's why it works only for your last line.
In your for loop, you should fill lists of lines so that you can pass them all as arguments to your CustomJS callback, after the loop. Then you need your customJS code to handle all the lines at once.

Here is an example:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, CustomJS
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
import numpy as np

figlist = [figure(title='Figure '+str(i),plot_width=200,plot_height=200) for i in range(6)]

x=np.arange(10)

linelist=[]
for fig in figlist:
    line0 = fig.line(x,x,color='blue')
    line1 = fig.line(x,x[::-1],color='red')
    line2 = fig.line(x,x**2,color='green')

    linelist+=[[line0,line1,line2]]

checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=['line0','line1','line2'],active=range(3))

iterable = [elem for part in [[('_'.join(['line',str(figid),str(lineid)]),line) for lineid,line in enumerate(elem)] for figid,elem in enumerate(linelist)] for elem in part]

checkbox_code = ''.join([elem[0]+'.visible=checkbox.active.includes('+elem[0].split('_')[-1]+');' for elem in iterable])

checkbox.callback = CustomJS(args={key:value for key,value in iterable+[('checkbox',checkbox)]}, code=checkbox_code)

grid = gridplot([figlist[:3]+[checkbox],figlist[3:]])

show(grid)
```

I also have more complex example code that use the line visibility toggle a lot, on [my bitbucket repository](https://bitbucket.org/rocheseb/bokeh/src/918c5036e00d9731a05554d941c6d4cc26a49997/check/?)

You do not need to pass the checkbox as an argument to its own callback (you can just use cb_obj), it's just that I often reuse the same "iterable" and "checkbox_code" for other widgets that can need it.